# searching values in array javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a built-in function in javascript to do this or this is only the option to go? Please look at the code below:

```
var arr=[1,3,4,'+','-', or whatever]

function value_check(user_click){

  var operators=['+','-','/','*','.']
  for (var i=0;i<operators.length;i++){
    if (arr[arr.length-1]==operators[i]){var value1='operator found';}
    if (user_click==operators[i]){
     var value2= value1;alert("consecutive operators"); break;
    }
  }
}
```

I think this code achieves what I intend to do but is there a simple and shorter way of doing this. In words, I want to achieve something like this:

```
if (arr[arr.length-1] && user_click BOTH ARE IN operators array) 
  alert("consecutive operators)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some options:

[JavaScript indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

[jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 0):

arrayName.indexOf() is what you are looking for.